# Where do I put my custom widget code for my wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, widget

I am creating a custom widget for my wordpress theme. The code I have breaks at a certain point.

I do not want to package the widget as a plugin so I am putting my code in the functions.php file.

This is my code:

```
class gmp_widget extends WP_Widget {
         function gmp_widget() {
               // widget actual processes

               $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'gmp_widget', 'description' => __('Example widget that displays a user\'s bio.','gmp-plugin'));
               $this->WP_Widget('gmp_widget_bio', __('Bio Widget','gmp-plugin'), $widget_ops);

        }

        public function form( $instance ) {
               // outputs the options form on admin
               $defaults = array( 'title' => __('My Bio', 'gmp-plugin'), 'name' => '', 'bio' => '');
               $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults);
               $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
               $name = strip_tags($instance['name']);
               $bio = strip_tags($instance['bio']);

               <p><?php _e('Title', 'gmp-plugin') ?>: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($name); ?>"</p>
               <p><?php _e('Name', 'gmp-plugin') ?>: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('name'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($name); ?>"</p>
               <p><?php _e('Bio', 'gmp-plugin') ?>: <textarea  class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('bio'); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr($title); ?></textarea></p>

        }

        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
               // processes widget options to be saved
               $instance = array();
               $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
               $instance['name'] = strip_tags($new_instance['name']);
               $instance['bio'] = strip_tags($new_instance['bio']);

               return $instance;
        }

        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
               // outputs the content of the widget
               extract($args);

               echo $before_widget;

               $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
               $name = empty($instance['name']) ? '&nbsp;' :
               apply_filters('widget_name', $instance['name']);
               $bio = empty($instance['bio']) ? '&nbsp;' :
               apply_filters('widget_bio', $instance['bio']);

               if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; };
               echo '<p>' .__('Name', 'gmp-plugin') .': ' . $name . '</p>';
               echo '<p>' .__('Bio', 'gmp-plugin') .': ' . $bio . '</p>';
               echo $after_widget;



              }

}
```

When it gets to the function form ($instance) I can see that the p tags are giving a syntax error as all the code below this goes from looking correct and all the right colour to black in my text editor which tells me there is a problem somewhere but I cannot figure out what it is. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the php tags you have to close the php tags then start your html like this

```
   public function form( $instance ) {
           // outputs the options form on admin
           $defaults = array( 'title' => __('My Bio', 'gmp-plugin'), 'name' => '', 'bio' => '');
           $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults);
           $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
           $name = strip_tags($instance['name']);
           $bio = strip_tags($instance['bio']); ?> //close php tag here 
// Now put your html
           <p><?php _e('Title', 'gmp-plugin') ?>: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($name); ?>"</p>
           <p><?php _e('Name', 'gmp-plugin') ?>: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('name'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($name); ?>"</p>
           <p><?php _e('Bio', 'gmp-plugin') ?>: <textarea  class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('bio'); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr($title); ?></textarea></p> //end of html
// Now open php tag
    <?php }
```

Comment: Thanks but when I add the php tags where you suggested in my wordpress admin area all the widgets disappear and my widget doesnt work; in the sense that it cannot be dragged and dropped in the sidebar location.

Comment: Check out the errors in the browser console like if there is any JS error or inspect the the rendered html in the browser's view source and double check you have closed html tags properly

Comment: @NeelamKhan Ome more thing to note that have you registered your widget ? like `register_widget('widgte class name');` Try this one http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/building-custom-wordpress-widgets/